# django join two tables based on values

Tags: python, django

I have django models like this:

```
class A():
  attr_a

class B():
  attr_b1
  attr_b2
  attr_b
  attr_fa = models.ForeignKey(A, to_field='attr_a')

class C():
  attr_c1
  attr_c2
  attr_c
  attr_fa = models.ForeignKey(A, to_field='attr_a')
```

Is it possible to join table B and C based on B.attr_b = C.attr_c and B.attr_fa = C.attr_fa?

the raw sql would be

```
select * from B, C where B.attr_b = C.attr_c and B.attr_fa = C.attr_fa
```

is it possible to use Django queryset to achieve this?

union is not possible as I also need fields like attr_b1, attr_b2, attr_c1, when column not same, I cannot union on two queryset

Answer (score 0):

You can use union() to combine query sets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#union

Stab in the dark, but might look something like this:

```
qs1 = B.objects.filter(
    attr_b__in=C.objects.all().values_list("attr_c"), 
    attr_fa__in=C.objects.all().values_list("attr_fa")
)

qs2 = C.objects.filter(
    attr_c__in=B.objects.all().values_list("attr_b"),
    attr_fa__in=B.objects.all().values_list("attr_fa")
)

result_qs = qs1.union(qs2)
```

Comment: union is not possible as I also need fields like attr_b1, attr_b2, attr_c1, when column not same, I cannot union on two queryset

Comment: In that case, you'd probably just want to do the manual sql query: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

If you definitely need a queryset, you could then run an ORM query based on the results of the custom sql query. (`B.objects.filter(id__in=[<B obj ids from custom sql>])` ...)

Comment: as I mentioned, I am trying to find a django way to do this. Also, I need to get attributes from both B and C, so B.objects.filter cannot give me correct result.